# Windows dev center Apps with same name

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store

I've two apps with same name, one is in phone and the other one is in desktop. Now, I created a universal app. Tab version have a small number of users, I need to upload new universal package to the phone version app.

But the problem is the App name automatically reserved to the Tab version, and the package name also. I'm not able to associate the application with the phone build in the store(because the app name is not reserved to this, there is no package name or package id for this in the store)

How can I resolve this issue without changing the name of the Phone Build?

Note: the dev center not showing delete option for this particular name.

Comment: There should be an option to associate your Windows Phone app and your Windows Store app with each other in the Windows Dev Center. Check both your apps' dev page to find the option.

Comment: There is no option for that, I've resolved the issue by changing the name of the Tab version.